# ngcookies angularjs how to include module i'm using sub controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

how to inject ngCookies service to the controller . i get an error stating injection failed as below Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/$injector/unpr?p0=%24cookiesProvider%20%3C-%20%24cookies%20%3C-%20Intake

```
app.controller("Intake", ["$scope", "$http", "$window", "$mdDialog", "$mdToast", "IntakeFactory", "fileUpload", 'ngCookies',  function ($scope, $http, $window,  $mdDialog,  $mdToast, $Intake, $fileUpload ,$cookieStore ) {
```

Comment: check the answer below and see if it is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to inject `ngCookies` not in your controller but in your module and your order of injections is incorrect.

```
var app= angular.module('myModuleName', ['ngCookies']);
```

And in your controller, you can access its properties by injecting `$cookieStore` like below

```
app.controller("Intake", ["$scope", "$http", "$window", "$mdDialog", "$mdToast", "IntakeFactory", "$fileUpload", '$cookieStore',  function ($scope, $http, $window,  $mdDialog,  $mdToast,IntakeFactory, $fileUpload ,$cookieStore )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use cookie like this :
(it won't work in this snippet becuase SO doesnot allow cookies HERE)

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngCookies']);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $cookies) {
  $cookies.putObject('cookieData', 'this is value stored by cookie');
  $scope.data = $cookies.getObject('cookieData');
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    {{data}}
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inject the service correctly.
Try the below one:-

```
angular.module('Intake', ['ngCookies']).controller('Intake', ['$cookies', function( $cookies){}])
```